# input[number] field does not display string value while binding in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, formatter

My form data is returned from a REST call.  Example data is:

```
{
    id: 4
    version: 3
    code: "ADSFASDF"
    definition: "asdflkj"
    value: "1234"
    active: "false"
    formula: false
    validTo: "2014-12-31T05:00:00"
    validFrom: "2010-12-31T10:00:00"
}
```

I'm running into trouble using `input[number]` and `input[date]` fields as they require the data to be a number or a date respectively and not a string.  Similar problems occur for booleans (check boxes), etc.

I thought I could get around it using a `$formattter`, but the value passed to the formatter is always "".  I presume this means the that `$formatter` is called after Angular has already tried to parse the data model.

Without having to initially cast everything in my controller, is there a way to cast the data via a directive, or within the HTML tag directly?

Ex:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="charge.value" jk-numeric id="chargeValue"/>
```

$formatter:

```
app.directive( 'jkNumeric',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                var stringToNum = function(text) {
                    if( angular.isNumber(text) )
                        return text;
                    else
                        return parseInt( text, 10);
                }

                // assign the parser and the formatter to the model
                ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(stringToNum);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you just send a number from the server? Or parse it as you get it

Comment: may be the value is "" because of the model (input) is not valid

Comment: @LoganMurphy The API was designed that way as the "value" can either be a numeric input or a formula.  If a formula, then it needs to be a String.

Comment: Then it is not a number.

Comment: @Whisher Not sure what you mean.  The model is valid; if I switch the input type to text, I see the value properly populated

Comment: @coma It is not a number as you can see in the JSON.  It is a number represented by a string.  That's precisely the issue that I am trying to resolve.

Comment: Create a service that makes the rest call and parses the value to a number, that way you can get the number even getting a formula.

Comment: just so you know the isNumber function returns false for strings even if they look like numbers

Comment: @EricB. You could do this way: http://plnkr.co/edit/82GrhL?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way :-

Set your directive to a **higher priority** so that the directive runs before `ng-model` does its `viewValue`/`modelValue` evaluation, and do a **2 way binding with `ngModel`** to get the actual value you set (and not the *viewValue of ngModel*), and to support async data assignment **keep a temporary watch**. You cannot possibly do it with `formatters` because they run after `ngModel` has evaluated the value.

```
.directive( 'jkNumeric',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            priority:999999, //<-- Give a higher priority
            scope: {         
               model:'=ngModel' //<-- A 2 way binding to read actual bound value not the ngModel view value
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

             //Perform whatever formatting you want to do.
             function stringToNum(text) {
                  return +text;
              }

             var unwatch = scope.$watch('model', function(val){
                if(!val) return;
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(stringToNum(val));
                ngModelCtrl.$render();
                unwatch();
              });

            }
        };
    });
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dgpx8R?p=preview)**

Another way to watch would be to watch on evaluated value of ngModel attribute.

```
            require: 'ngModel',
            priority:999999,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

              function formatToNumber(text) {
                  //do something and return numeric value
              }

             scope.$watch(function(){
                 return scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel); //evaluate the scope value
             }, function(val){
                 if(!val) return;
                 ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(formatToNumber(val));
                 ngModelCtrl.$render();
              });
```

**[Plnk2](http://plnkr.co/edit/GzKNoA?p=preview)**

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've ever seen for an angularjs question I was looking at answering myself. Great stuff.

Comment: @PSL Thanks - at first looks a little convoluted, and am surprised that Angular requires this much effort for something fairly simple, but I see that Angular is like that sometimes.  Why do you deregister the watch expression once it has been executed?  What if the model is changed a second time async?  Was that intentional or not a case you were trying to protect?

Comment: @EricB. Yeah i put that intentionally, if it is only for the first time assignment.. You can keep it if you have a refresh scenario otherwise why to keep a watch, it can be destroyed. hence.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the full purpose of the isolated scope.  Can you not just put the watch on attrs.ngModel directly?  How does the isolated scope help?

Comment: @EricB. Yes you can do, but no point watching on it directly on `attrs.ngModel` you would need to do `scope.$eval` on the watch evaluation function. Providing isolated scope with 2 way, you can avoid doing that. Anyways i will update with that option as well on how to do it. Actually i generally prefer isolated scope because it is completely separated out except for the configured value.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like:

```
app.directive( 'jkNumeric',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                if (angular.isString(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(parseInt(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, 10));
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Very similar to @PSL's answer, however he pointed out the need to have a higher priority level.